# subsetting a dataframe by a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

I have the following data with the ID of subjects.

```
V1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  2
12  2
13  2
14  2
15  2
16  4
17  4
18  4
19  4
20  4
21  4
22  4
23  4
24  4
```

I want to subset all the rows of the data where V1 == 4. This way I can see which observations relate to subject 4.

For example, the correct output would be

```
16  4
17  4
18  4
19  4
20  4
21  4
22  4
23  4
24  4
```

However, the output I'm given after subsetting does not give me the correct rows . It simply gives me.

```
V1
1  4
2  4
3  4
4  4
5  4
6  4
7  4
8  4
```

I'm unable to tell which observations relate to subject 4, as observations 1:8 are for subject 2.

I've tried the usual methods, such as

```
condition<- df == 4
df[condition]
```

How can I subset the data so I'm given back a dataset that shows the correct row numbers for subject 4.

Comment: you don't have a header for one of your column

Comment: Try `which(df$V1 == 4)`

Comment: `subset(df, V1==4)` ?

Comment: it seems like your id are rownames. If you really need them, it would be easier to make them an actual variable `df$id <- rownames(df)` and then use regular subsetting `df[df$V1 == 4,]`

Comment: Might as well add `df[df$V1 == 4,,drop=F]` too

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the subset function:

```
subset(df,df$V1==4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution since posting.

```
newdf <- subset(df, V1 == 4).
```

However i'm still very interested in other solutions to this problems, so please post if you're aware of another method.

Comment: you shouldn't use `R` objects as names for user created objects: you should call your data.frame something other than `df`.

Comment: @stasg, this is _very_ commonly done in R questions on SO..

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, i know :(

Comment: the object name `df` is for the sake of clarity. My actual data.frame is not called this.

Comment: you probably shouldn't use `R` object names for any reason. there are many alternatives `df1`, `df_`, etc..

Comment: @stasg that argument is true in a general sense, but shouldn't be compared to using `c`, `t`, or `str` as a name. Those are especially problematic because they are commonly used. When was the last time you used `df`? You're right that it is suboptimal but it is very quick and useful for examples.

Comment: @PierreLafortune true enough -- i don't recall last time i used `df`! however, i guess, not using _any_ `R` core object names at all would encourage good coding practices and instil certain discipline.

Comment: I agree. But I gotta insist on an exception here. It is not only historically used as a default name but actually works well. It is likened to the slang that has become common usage. For example the machine with wings that flies through the air was originally called the "aeroplane" to describe the science going on. So many people mistakenly called it "airplane" that eventually it stuck. :)

Comment: @PierreLafortune okay, it is difficult to disagree with this! :)